# how get proper http trace response in fastapi?

Tags: python, http, fastapi

here is my code:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.trace("/")
def test_trace():
    ...
```

and this is the response:
curl -v -X TRACE http://127.0.0.1:8000

```
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< date: Sat, 03 Sep 2022 15:52:55 GMT
< server: uvicorn
< content-length: 4
< content-type: application/json
< 
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
```

but I want something like this with **TRACE** **header** in it:

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< date: Sat, 03 Sep 2022 15:52:55 GMT
< server: uvicorn
< content-length: 4
< content-type: application/json

< TRACE / HTTP/1.1
< Host: www.ssfkz.si
< User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0
```

Comment: Are you asking how you can make `curl` print the _request_ headers as well?

Comment: no, I want to return the trace header just like the example above

Comment: @amirbahador Are you looking for a standard TRACE implementation where the HTTP request is echoed back as-is to the client as per the [RFC](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7231.html#TRACE)? If so, you might wanna look at other frameworks as high-level frameworks like FastAPI don't do well with such low-level HTTP manipulation.

Comment: @rdas this probably can be done with FastAPI as well. One could take the details of a `Request` object and just return then in a `Response` object.

Answer (score 0):

Headers (and pretty much every detail of interest) are customizable through the use of the Response object.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Response

app = FastAPI()

@app.trace("/")
def test_trace(response: Response):
    response.headers["TRACE"] = "HTTP/1.1"
    response.status_code = 200
    ...
    return {}
```

Before asking on SO, please make sure to read (and/or search) the official documentation (https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/response-headers/).

**EDIT**

Even though the OP mentioned setting the **TRACE** "header", officially, the implementation of this HTTP method does not mention setting such headers, but rather, returning exactly what was received in the trace request.

An approximate behavior might be achieved by using:

```
@app.trace("/")
def test_trace(request: Request, response: Response):
    for k,v in request.headers.items():
        response.headers[k] = v
    # repeat for every property that should be echo-ed
    response.headers["Content-Type"] = "message/http" # RFC 7231
    response.status_code = 200 # RFC 7231
    return {}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but that's not what I wanted 
1 - the trace header is lower case
2- that didn't return two section response part one
HTTP
and second part
TRACE

Comment: what do you mean by "two section response part one HTTP and second part TRACE"? can you edit your question to clearly state this? As for " the trace header is lower case", feel free to edit the code to `response.headers["trace"] = "HTTP/1.1"` as you can include custom headers in any form you like. Mind that custom headers should begin with the characther `X`.

Comment: no, i mean trace should be uppercase but your code return lowercase

Comment: do you mean? `response.headers["TRACE"] = "http/1.1"`. Have you actually tried the code?

Comment: "two section response" i mean just like the example I used in question there is first part with HTTP headers and then there is  second part TRACE headers

Comment: yes i tried your code 
it returns this ==>  trace: HTTP/1.1

Comment: What is the purpose of a "two section response"? The structure of HTTP request/response headers is clearly defined in, for example, RFC 7230 (section 3.2): "Each header field consists of a case-insensitive field name followed by a colon (":"), optional leading whitespace, the field value, and  optional trailing whitespace.". This RFC also mentions (as seen above) that the key-value pairs should be case-insensitive (as in "the case does not matter").

Comment: The TRACE line is not a header in the example that OP posted. This will not match what the OP wants.

Comment: That's indeed correct. Even though the OP mentioned a Trace "header", as per RFC 7231: "The final recipient of the request SHOULD reflect the message received".

Comment: I have edited my answer to at least echo the received headers, other details of interest could be reflected in the same manner. Unfortunately, RFCs seem to contain little to no information about what TRACE echoes, as I assume it doesn't only echo request headers.